# Erro ao acessar o mysql workbench usando docker-compose

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysql, docker

Estou começando a trabalhar com containers e me deparei com um problema.
Configura meu arquivo docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'
volumes:
  data:
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123456
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=loja
  App:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    links:
      - mysql
    ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

mas qndo vou conectar o phpmyadmin ele mostra esse erro.
 mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.3' (using password: YES)

e quando verifico os logs do container tem esses erros

```
Attaching to loja_App_1_808ba5614963, loja_mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f
App_1_808ba5614963 | phpMyAdmin not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
App_1_808ba5614963 | Complete! phpMyAdmin has been successfully copied to /var/www/html
App_1_808ba5614963 | /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/supervisor/options.py:461: UserWarning: Supervisord is running as root and it is searching for its configuration file in default locations (including its current working directory); you probably want to specify a "-c" argument specifying an absolute path to a configuration file for improved security.
App_1_808ba5614963 |   'Supervisord is running as root and it is searching '
App_1_808ba5614963 | 2019-01-06 19:47:05,147 CRIT Supervisor is running as root.  Privileges were not dropped because no user is specified in the config file.  If you intend to run as root, you can set user=root in the config file to avoid this message.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.574433Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.576710Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.24) starting as process 1 ...
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.599243Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.599281Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.599291Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.599300Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.599309Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.599317Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.600883Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.642884Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.646957Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.706189Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.726936Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.741760Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.759797Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 1628983
App_1_808ba5614963 | 2019-01-06 19:47:05,152 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor.d/nginx.ini" during parsing
App_1_808ba5614963 | 2019-01-06 19:47:05,152 INFO Included extra file "/etc/supervisor.d/php.ini" during parsing
App_1_808ba5614963 | 2019-01-06 19:47:05,205 INFO RPC interface 'supervisor' initialized
App_1_808ba5614963 | 2019-01-06 19:47:05,206 CRIT Server 'unix_http_server' running without any HTTP authentication checking
App_1_808ba5614963 | 2019-01-06 19:47:05,206 INFO supervisord started with pid 1
App_1_808ba5614963 | 2019-01-06 19:47:06,210 INFO spawned: 'php-fpm' with pid 21
App_1_808ba5614963 | 2019-01-06 19:47:06,219 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 22
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.759828Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 1628992
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.759839Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:55.759848Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.084317Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.084516Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.084717Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.565786Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.573294Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.573319Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.573782Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.626055Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.24 started; log sequence number 1628992
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.626576Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.627567Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:56.758789Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 190106 19:46:56
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:58.033962Z 0 [Warning] System table 'plugin' is expected to be transactional.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:58.061334Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:58.062481Z 0 [Warning] Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:58.072832Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:58.088643Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:58.091510Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:46:58.091558Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.210934Z 0 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.211334Z 0 [Warning] Failed to open optimizer cost constant tables
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.402998Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.404074Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.404092Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@913e64c89d16' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.514859Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_leap_second' is expected to be transactional.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.514880Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_name' is expected to be transactional.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.514886Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone' is expected to be transactional.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.514891Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition_type' is expected to be transactional.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.514896Z 0 [Warning] System table 'time_zone_transition' is expected to be transactional.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.638394Z 0 [Warning] System table 'servers' is expected to be transactional.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.644777Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_current: expected column 'NESTING_EVENT_TYPE' at position 15 to have type enum('TRANSACTION','STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT', found type enum('STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT').
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.645412Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_history: expected column 'NESTING_EVENT_TYPE' at position 15 to have type enum('TRANSACTION','STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT', found type enum('STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT').
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.646028Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_history_long: expected column 'NESTING_EVENT_TYPE' at position 15 to have type enum('TRANSACTION','STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT', found type enum('STATEMENT','STAGE','WAIT').
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.668344Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_user_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.669123Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_account_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.675683Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.setup_actors is wrong. Expected 5, found 3. Created with MySQL 50642, now running 50724. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.677312Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.setup_objects: expected column 'OBJECT_TYPE' at position 0 to have type enum('EVENT','FUNCTION','PROCEDURE','TABLE','TRIGGER', found type enum('TABLE').
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.679639Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.table_lock_waits_summary_by_table is wrong. Expected 68, found 73. Created with MySQL 50642, now running 50724. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.680190Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.threads is wrong. Expected 17, found 14. Created with MySQL 50642, now running 50724. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.680730Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_stages_current is wrong. Expected 12, found 10. Created with MySQL 50642, now running 50724. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.681271Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_stages_history is wrong. Expected 12, found 10. Created with MySQL 50642, now running 50724. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.681808Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_stages_history_long is wrong. Expected 12, found 10. Created with MySQL 50642, now running 50724. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.682856Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_stages_summary_by_account_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.683417Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_stages_summary_by_user_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.684987Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_statements_current is wrong. Expected 41, found 40. Created with MySQL 50642, now running 50724. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.686079Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_statements_history is wrong. Expected 41, found 40. Created with MySQL 50642, now running 50724. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.686676Z 0 [ERROR] Column count of performance_schema.events_statements_history_long is wrong. Expected 41, found 40. Created with MySQL 50642, now running 50724. Please use mysql_upgrade to fix this error.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.687754Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_account_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.688361Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.events_statements_summary_by_user_by_event_name: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.696356Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_statements_summary_by_program' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.696418Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_current' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.696460Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_history' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.696503Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_history_long' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.696551Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.696597Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.696643Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.696688Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_summary_by_host_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.696734Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'events_transactions_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.697342Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.users: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.697966Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table performance_schema.accounts: expected column 'USER' at position 0 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.701528Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'memory_summary_global_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.701585Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'memory_summary_by_account_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.701630Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'memory_summary_by_host_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.701676Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'memory_summary_by_thread_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.701720Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'memory_summary_by_user_by_event_name' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.701761Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'table_handles' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.701803Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'metadata_locks' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.701866Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_connection_configuration' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.701910Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_group_members' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.701957Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_connection_status' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702000Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_applier_configuration' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702042Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_applier_status' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702087Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_applier_status_by_coordinator' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702130Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_applier_status_by_worker' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702174Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'replication_group_member_stats' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702215Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'prepared_statements_instances' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702258Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'user_variables_by_thread' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702299Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'status_by_account' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702339Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'status_by_host' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702380Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'status_by_thread' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702423Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'status_by_user' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702464Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'global_status' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702504Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_status' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702544Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'variables_by_thread' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702585Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'global_variables' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702626Z 0 [ERROR] Native table 'performance_schema'.'session_variables' has the wrong structure
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702768Z 0 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.db: expected column 'User' at position 2 to have type char(32), found type char(16).
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.702815Z 0 [ERROR] mysql.user has no `Event_priv` column at position 28
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.704821Z 0 [ERROR] Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | 2019-01-06T19:47:00.705219Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
mysql_1_f8fee6ca074f | Version: '5.7.24'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

e já procurei bastante e não achei uma solução.

Comment: O título da pergunta sugere que você esteja com problemas para *"acessar o mysql workbench"*. Mas no corpo da pergunta você diz que está com erro para acessar o *PhpMyAdmin*. Ambos são **ferramentas para gerenciar o banco de dados MySQL**. A pesar dos erros, o MySQL está rodando: *"[Note] mysqld: ready for connections."*; O erro que retorna no *PhpMyAdmin* sugere que o usuário `root` através do host `172.26.0.3` não está autorizado a conectar-se ou a senha está incorreta, como o próprio erro sugere: *"Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.3'"*;

Comment: [...] Você consegue acessar o *MySQL* através do Workbench ou terminal? Está rodando o servidor do *MySQL* localmente?

Comment: estou rodando o servidor Mysql sim, mas tando o workbench e o phpmyadmin dá o mesmo erro de conexao. estou usando a imagem ambientum/mysql e o serviço esta ativo.

Answer (score 0):

```
phpmyadmin:
   image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
   container_name: phpmyadmin
   depends_on:
     - mysql
   links:
     - mysql
   ports:
     - 80:80
   environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
     - MYSQL_USER=root
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
     - PMA_HOST=mysql
```

Tente algo parecido com isso